# Cannot display image on windows server

Tags: laravel-5.4, iis-8.5

I am hitting this url to display an image

http://glilittest.com/uploads/claim_document_uploads/2017-1/2017-1_loan_contract1.jpg

but it's giving me this error

[image]

this is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I can confirm that the path to the image is correct. Directory browsing is enabled and all permissions are given to the folder.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the problem lied with the site's authentication setting. When I enabled `Anonymous Authentication` in authentication settings, it worked perfectly.